# tf.keras: Feeding extra values to model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

Say you have e.g. a boolean `tf.placeholder`, and you want to feed it when you call `Model.fit`. How would you do it? Below is some runnable dummy code that illustrates the problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# A boolean value that should have some effect of something
do_stuff = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
# If do_stuff is true, return tf.ones else tf.zeros, and a 1 or 0 label
if_dostuff = lambda: [tf.ones((5, 5)), tf.constant(1)]
if_not_dostuff = lambda: [tf.zeros((5, 5)), tf.constant(0)]
X, Y_true = tf.cond(do_stuff, if_dostuff, if_not_dostuff)
# Make some dummy labels
# Do some random model operation
X_input = Input(shape=(5, 5))
layer_mod = Flatten()(X_input)
layer_mod = Dense(1)(layer_mod)
out_model = Model(inputs=[X_input], outputs=[layer_mod])
# Compile model
out_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy
)
### Other ops with other models and summaries etc. ###
out_model.fit(...) # What do I do at this point?
```

Keep in mind that the boolean is just to keep things simple. In reality I have strings that are iterator handles that needs to be fed (based on what dataset I want to train).

How can I do keras' amazing `model.fit` interface with this sort of layout?

An alternative would be what I ask in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687011/access-training-operation-in-a-tf-keras-model)

Comment: Where do you want to use your boolean? Is it in the loss?

Comment: @Anakin Please read the text just below the code :) Also -- here it is used when getting `X,Y_true`.

Comment: What I do not understand is...if your boolean value is independent of the model prediction, you can already get your `X, Y_true` according to the boolean and pass it to your `fit` function. So, why do you need the boolean in the `fit`? And if it is dependent on the training, how?

Comment: @Anakin I appreciate you're trying to help. I am not using a boolean. Using boolean is just to keep things simple. In reality I have strings that are iterator handles that needs to be fed (based on what dataset I want to train). This is also what I have written right below the code. The model I'm working on does depend on training, since the values in the iterators are undetermined.